# how to connect C wire to Weil-McLain EG-65 Series-5 gas steam boiler

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

Which of the Weil-McLain EG-65 transformer terminal should I use for a thermostat common wire? (I am trying to connect a nest learning thermostat to that boiler and it needs a common wire). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [control wiring supplement](http://www.weil-mclain.com/sites/default/files/field-file/egh-control-supplement-universal-control-systems_1.pdf) for your boiler, there should be a C terminal on the transformer, adjacent to the R terminal.  Look for the terminal on the transformer with the green wires going to it.